# C# Date format {0:t} - {0:t+1} 00:00 - 01:00

Tags: c#, sql

I have a date in C# which I would like to show as HH:mm - HH:mm(+1) format e.g:

```
00:00 - 01:00
01:00 - 02:00
02:00 - 03:00
```

Can someone advise how I can accomplish this? I am currently using {0:t} - {0:t} but i need to add +1 hour to the right side.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do calculations within a format string.  You'll need to use two values.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the time twice, adding one hour to the second parameter.

For example:

```
String.Format("{0:t} - {1:t}",time,time.AddHours(1));
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is that this is on a telerik report, which means i am limited to just the one date and cannot apply the above.

Comment: @Tommy Those are good details (dependencies, limitations) that you should include in the question.

Comment: @Tommy can you add the second time to the data source somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Can it not be done using simple date formatting? {0:t} - {0:t+1} something along those lines?

Comment: It can't be done with format strings. Can't you use a calculated field in your data source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.AddHours(int)` method to accomplish this, so for example:

`DateTime thisDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
   thisDate.ToShortTimeString();`

Comment: Thanks the problem is that this is on a telerik report, which means i am limited to just the one date and cannot apply the above.